# Using rails update_all to copy current value from other cell?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing an rails 4 (using postgresql) app where performance is important. With that said I would like to not have to loop through my object to update these columns. I would be happy if it's possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with update_all/as few db queries as possible.

To the problem. Say I have model User with three columns a,b,c.

I want to update column a with the current value of column b and then put the current value of column c into b (without it affecting column a).

I Tried with both:

1)

```
User.update_all('a = b, b = c')
```

2)

```
User.update_all('a = b')
User.update_all('b = c')
```

I'm guessing the columns get linked on db level. But is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do without selecting the values from each row?

Comment: Your code looks correct. The docs say that the argument should be a "string, array, or hash representing the SET part of an SQL statement." What problem are you having?

Comment: I don't think update_all is going to work in this case. You may need to use raw SQL (`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("...")`) where you hold the value in a variable while swapping. I'm not familiar with how to do that in PostGreSQL. The other option is to rename the columns. That will also require a bit of juggling because you can't have two columns with the same name at the same time.

Comment: @TomL Suprisingly, it looks like in PostgreSQL `UPDATE tbl SET a = b, b = c` works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/82461/1 Without knowing what problem Molle is having, though, it's hard to say what the right solution in Rails is.

Comment: @Jordan you are quite correct.  I was thinking about it as more of a "b to a and a to b" type of thing but that's not it. I don't see the problem either.

Comment: Thanks for the anwsers guys! You are correct and it works fine. The problem was me selecting the wrong values in the view after a copy paste.. my bad.